# Python List Comprehension and 'not in'

Tags: python, python-2.x

I'm getting started with Python and is currently learning about list comprehensions so this may sound really strange.

**Question:** Is it possible to use list comprehension to create a list of elements in `t` that is not found in `s`?

I tried the following and it gave me an error:

```
>>> t = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
>>> s = [1, 3, 5]
>>>[t for t not in s]

[t for t not in s]
           ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

Comment: A comprehension can only have two kinds of clauses: `for spam in eggs` and `if bacon`. If you can figure out how to write what you want in terms of a `for` loop or an `if` check, you're set. (In this case, you can.) If not, you either need to factor pieces out into functions, or write an explicit loop block statement instead of a comprehension.

Answer (score 71, accepted):

Try this:

```
[x for x in t if x not in s]
```

You can nest any for if statements in list comprehensions. Try this identation, to get really long chains of conditionals, with a clearer intuition about what the code is doing.

```
my_list = [(x,a)
           for x in t
           if x not in s
           if x > 0
           for a in y
           ...]
```

See?

Answer (score 6):

```
[item  for item  in t if item not in s]
```

Comment: This is identical to [Lucas' answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/19507719/119527) which was given earlier, and therefore completely redundant.

Comment: slow typing is sin for programmers

Comment: That's why I didn't down-vote. Unfortunately, you'll often find that Stack Overflow is a race to the first answer that is correct.

Answer (score 2):

I know you're asking about list comprehensions, but I wanted to point out that *this specific* problem would be better accomplished using [`set`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#set)s. The result you want is the difference of set `t` and `s`:

```
>>> t = {1,2,3,4,5}
>>> s = {1,3,5}
>>>
>>> t - s
set([2, 4])
>>>
>>> t.difference(s)
set([2, 4])
```

Just hoping to expand your knowledge of the tools Python provides to you.

Comment: This may not be useful if `t` needs to preserve order and any repeated elements... Also... only one needs to be a set here - possibly use the smaller to start with, eg: `set(s).symmetric_difference(t)`

Comment: @JonClements Great insight. I appreciate the feedback.

Comment: Indeed, only one needs to be a set: `"Note, the non-operator versions of union(), intersection(), difference(), and symmetric_difference(), issubset(), and issuperset() methods will accept any iterable as an argument. In contrast, their operator based counterparts require their arguments to be sets."`

Answer (score 1):

For better efficiency, use a set:

```
mySet = set(s)
result = [x for x in t if x not in mySet]
```

Testing membership of a set is done is O(1), but testing membership in a list is O(n).

Comment: This calls `set` multiple times.

Comment: Actually, this result will be more slow, because will create a set of s too. Each time s if checked, i guess

Comment: And, just another way: `list(ifilterfalse(set(s).__contains__, t))`