# Python 3 - list comprehension "if not in list"

Tags: python, python-3.x, list-comprehension

I have a list1 containing different integers.
Now, I want to create a second list (list2), that contains all elements of list1 without doubles. And I want to create list2 with list comprehension, without the need of defining it first as an empty list:

```
list1 = [3,3,2,1,5,6,1,5,7]
list2 = [i for i in list1 if i not in list2]
print(list2)
```

That case would be perfect for set(), I know.
But why it is not working with a list comprehension?

In these threads I found, that my list2-syntax should be fine:

- [Python List Comprehension and 'not in'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19507714/python-list-comprehension-and-not-in)
- [List comprehension with if statement](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15474933/list-comprehension-with-if-statement)

Both top voted answers suggest a syntax like

```
[y for y in a if y not in b]
```

Comment: Simple - the list comprehension evaluates _before_ the assignment to `list2`

Comment: So it is not possible to solve this situation with a list comprehension? So where is the difference between my situation and the suggested syntax in the top voted answers?

Comment: This will throw a `NameError`, because `list2` does not exist when the list comprehension is being evaluated. more generally, you cannot refer to the resulting list in a list comprehension, list comprehensions and other comprehension constructs are not "one-line for loops", and you shouldn't think of them as such. They are for expressing *mapping/filtering* operations that result in a new container or iterable.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Removes duplicates from nested list without use of set](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63223521/removes-duplicates-from-nested-list-without-use-of-set)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's because you're defining list2's contents self-referentially.
While syntactically it's correct, semantically it's meaningless - list2 isn't defined yet when you refer to it in the filter/guard part of the list comprehension.

Comment: A similar question was asked here:

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2638478/recursive-list-comprehension-in-python

Comment: when I define list2 before using the list comprehension, there are still double elements in list2:
list1 = [3,3,2,1,5,6,1,5,7]
list2 = [i for i in list1 if i not in list2]
print(list2)

Comment: @laura.neukamp of course, because creating another list object doesn't modify list2, why would it? Again, list comprehensions are declarative constructs that describe a mapping/filtering operations to produce a new list object

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga: YEAH! Now I got the point! That is so logical and clear.
Thank You for this explanation.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not 100% sure but i believe the list isn't fully populated until the comprehension is complete.

You could simply do this if you were able to not use list comprehension

```
List(Set(list1))
```

Another option (not what you wanted either)

```
list1 = [3,3,2,1,5,6,1,5,7]
list2 = []
for itm in list1:
    if itm not in list2:
        list2.append(itm)
```

Comment: of course, I know. But I want to unterstand why it is not possible with a list comprehension in my intendet way?

Comment: Your checking if its contained in list2 but I believe list2 hasn't been populated yet, not until the comprehension is complete.

Comment: together with the answer of @juanpa.arrivillaga, this is the solution. And now I understand my problem and my error in thinking. Should always remember to write code I unterstand and I can read. Thank You Lews Morris!

Comment: Don't forget to accept the answer if it helped you :)