# Removes duplicates from nested list without use of set

Tags: python, python-3.x, string, list

I have a list of lists and I want to remove duplicates within each nested list.

```py
Input: [['c', 'p', 'p'], ['a', 'a', 'a'], ['t', 't', 'p']]
```

```py
Output: [['c', 'p'], ['a'], ['t','p']]
```

**The key here is that I cannot use the set() function or fromkeys().**

Here is the code I have,

```py
ans = []

for i in letters:
    [ans.append([x]) for x in i if x not in ans]
```

which returns

```py
[['c'], ['p'], ['p'], ['a'], ['a'], ['a'], ['t'], ['t'], ['p']]
```

which isn't what I want.

Comment: "I cannot use the set() function or fromkeys()." Why not?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can iterate over the inner list and check if that character is already present or not

```
inputList = [['c', 'p', 'p'], ['a', 'a', 'a'], ['t', 't', 'p']]
result = []

for l in inputList:
    # create a empty list to store intermediate result 
    tmp = []
    # iterate over sublist
    for ch in l:
        if ch not in tmp: tmp.append(ch)
    result.append(tmp)
print(result)
```

Answer (score 1):

You tripped yourself up with the nested lists. A second loop is necessary to filter the elements. Although it's quite inefficient, you can write your attempt as

```
ans = []
for i in letters:
    k = []
    for j in i:
        if j not in k:
            k.append(j)
    ans.append(k)
```

You can likely shorten this code, but not reduce its complexity.

To do that, you can use something `sorted` and `itertools.groupby`. this is still less efficient than a hash table, but better than linear lookup (although it likely doesn't matter much for short arrays):

```
ans = [[k for k, _ in groupby(sorted(i))] for i in letters]
```

Answer (score 0):

Since you can't use `set()` or `fromkeys()`, I would suggest a normal loop iteration, each time checking if value is already present:

```
lst = [['c', 'p', 'p'], ['a', 'a', 'a'], ['t', 't', 'p']]

new_lst = []
for x in lst:
    res = []
    for y in x:
        if y not in res:
            res.append(y)           
    new_lst.append(res)
    
print(new_lst)
```

Ideally, `new_lst` here should be a set.

Answer (score 0):

```
list=[['c', 'p', 'p'], ['a', 'a', 'a'], ['t', 't', 'p']]
ans=[]
for sublist in list:
    temp=[]
    for ch in sublist:
        if ch not in temp:
            temp.append(ch)
    ans.append(temp)
print(ans)
```

#I think it should work, very simple, it could be more complex

Answer (score 0):

Just ignore every instance of a letter until it is the last one.

- for every sublist of input:
  `[[...] for sub in input]`
- store the letter if it isn't in the rest of the sublist:
  `[ltr for i, ltr in enumerate(sub) if ltr not in sub[i+1:]]`

Put it together and you have:

```
input  = [['c', 'p', 'p'], ['a', 'a', 'a'], ['t', 't', 'p']]
output = [[ltr for i, ltr in enumerate(sub) if ltr not in sub[i+1:]] for sub in input]
print(output) #[['c', 'p'], ['a'], ['t', 'p']]
```